# Represent huge amount of polygons with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm actually aiming to represent a huge GeoJSON file using Leaflet (JS). The GeoJSON size would be around 300 Mb, so I'm looking to raster the polygons while being at a higher zoom, and vectorizing (on the bound) as we zoom into the region I'm interested in.

[image]

I did some research, I found this extension [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/c67e5551b21c68dc8299)
but it looks like its not maintained and it doesn't raster then overtime or over zoom vectorize the polygons.

Comment: Have you limited the attributes to what you really need? Have you reduced the coordinate precision to a reasonable value? Have you tried TopoJSON?

Comment: No but in fact, I want to load just the bounds, like the area I'm interested in, instead of loading the whole polygons at once.

Comment: Do you use any map server? You may publich your data as wms for higher zoom levels and load vector data for lower zoom levels.

Comment: No I'm not using any map server, there is no way to achieve this using only leaflet without a map server ?!